# What can be used to convert a long date into just days so format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to just YYYY-MM-DD in Postgresql 12

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a bunch of dates which I am trying to use for archiving. In postgresql 12 I am trying to get a whole bunch of row data into a more simplistic format for processing.

Currently it looks as follows:

```
641860323   2021-05-05 08:37:40.414 +0100
641860324   2021-05-05 08:37:40.497 +0100
641860325   2021-05-05 08:37:40.510 +0100
641860326   2021-05-05 08:37:40.513 +0100
641860327   2021-05-05 08:37:40.541 +0100
641860328   2021-05-05 08:37:40.575 +0100
641860329   2021-05-05 08:37:40.623 +0100
641860330   2021-05-05 08:37:40.720 +0100
641860331   2021-05-05 08:37:40.883 +0100
641860332   2021-05-05 08:37:41.178 +0100
641860333   2021-05-05 08:37:41.185 +0100
641860334   2021-05-05 08:37:41.251 +0100
641860335   2021-05-05 08:37:41.315 +0100
641860336   2021-05-05 08:37:41.318 +0100
641860337   2021-05-05 08:37:41.326 +0100
641860338   2021-05-05 08:37:41.348 +0100
641860339   2021-05-05 08:37:41.443 +0100
641860340   2021-05-05 08:37:41.522 +0100
641860341   2021-05-05 08:37:41.663 +0100
641860342   2021-05-05 08:37:42.091 +0100
641860343   2021-05-05 08:37:42.097 +0100
641860345   2021-05-05 08:37:42.290 +0100
641860344   2021-05-05 08:37:42.292 +0100
641860346   2021-05-05 08:37:42.294 +0100
641860347   2021-05-05 08:37:42.437 +0100
641860348   2021-05-05 08:37:42.490 +0100
```

This would go on for each day and am looking to get a format with an end result such as the below which is a count of the amount for each day:

```
2021-05-05 |  8216682
```

What could I use to achieve this? If I try and do a group by as using the below get OOM issues.

```
SELECT event_created, COUNT(*)
FROM tmp_schema.tmp_game_archive
GROUP BY event_created
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the timestamp to a `date`:

```
SELECT event_created::date, COUNT(*)
FROM tmp_schema.tmp_game_archive
GROUP BY event_created::date
ORDER BY 1
```